# Spring Boot + Logback springProperty. SpringProperty undefined after logging level changing

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I have Spring Boot application and set in application.properties next variables:

```
logging.config=file:./xxx_logback.xml
appName=myapp
appVersion=1.0
```

Application create correctly logfile after start. But when I change logging level, logback create new logfile with name "appName_IS_UNDEFINED-appVersion_IS_UNDEFINED". I use next logback config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>
    <!-- To enable JMX Management -->
    <jmxConfigurator/>
    
    <springProperty scope="context" name="appName" source="appName"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="appVersion" source="appVersion"/>

    <appender name="FILE-APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/${appName}-${appVersion}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>logs/${appName}-${appVersion}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>utf-8</charset>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="warn">
   
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-APPENDER"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="xxx.xxx" level="warn"/>

</configuration>
```

Can't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the reason is this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.logback-extensions

The extensions cannot be used with Logback’s configuration scanning. If you attempt to do so, making changes to the configuration file results in an error.